# vm ware script error

Tags: installation, vmware

I have downloaded version 6.01 of VMware Player onto the Desktop of my Windows 8 laptop but everytime I try to install it I get the following error...

An error has occurred in the script on this page
Line:   1089
Char:   7
Error:   Expected ')'
Code:   0
URL:  file:///C:/Users/CB's/AppData/Local/Temp/vmware_1387286925/index.htm?lang=1033&locale=1033

Do you want to continue running scripts on this page?
Yes/No

I have followed the Knowledgebase article advising me to clear out my browsing history and cache and try downloading again but nothing changes.

If I click Yes or No the install window goes blank and my Laptops fan starts running but nothing appears to be happening. If I try to abort the installation by right clicking the VM taskbar icon I get a message telling me an installation is in progress and to wait until this finishes...I have waited over an hour and the nearest I have got to an installation is an empty VMware Folder in My Documents.

Can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to your c drive and make folder name it "Tmp"
2. right click on mycomputer and click proporties
3. Go to advanced system
4. click on environment variables
   you will find two temporary folders located
5. click on the first temp and click on edit
6. change the value to "c:\Tmp"
7. Do the same for the other temp
8. Then restart your pc

done u can install ur vmware